# LeetCode 1: Two Sum

Tags: python, java, c++, beginner, programming-challenge

This is an easy level LeetCode question, obviously not much code to review. I'm posting C++/Java/Python here. If you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you!

#### Problem

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such
> that they add up to a specific target.
>
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and
> you may not use the same element twice.
>
> Example:
>
> Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,
>
> Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9, return [0, 1].

#### C++

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> &nums, int target) {
        unordered_map<int, int> index_map;

        for (int index = 0;; index++) {
            auto iter = index_map.find(target - nums[index]);

            if (iter != index_map.end())
                return vector<int> {index, iter -> second};

            index_map[nums[index]] = index;
        }
    }
};
```

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] indices = new int[2];
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int index = 0; index < nums.length; index++) {
            if (map.containsKey(target - nums[index])) {
                indices[1] = index;
                indices[0] = map.get(target - nums[index]);
                return indices;
            }
            map.put(nums[index], index);
        }
        return indices;
    }
}
```

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        index_map = {}
        for index, num in enumerate(nums):
            if target - num in index_map:
                return index_map[target - num], index
            index_map[num] = index
```

#### Reference

- [LeetCode 1: Two Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/)
- [LeetCode 1 Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_votes&query=)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the C++ solution, the map should be from `int` to `std::size_t`, since that's the standard data type for indexes.

The method signature looks strange: `nums` should be a `const` reference, and the return type should just be a `std::pair`. But that's probably the fault of LeetCode. Or more generally: Don't blindly assume that these coding challenges provide good code to begin with.

Comment: … or that they require good coding skills. (Many of them are basically *puzzles*, and not even programming puzzles but *math* puzzles.)

Comment: Then again, many resource limits are carefully crafted such that the bigger problem instances don't stand a chance to meet the constraints with (notably) sub-optimal asymptotic requirements.

Answer (score 6):

I'm answering about `java` code, your method signature is the  following:

> `public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {}`

In this way you are bound to create an instance of your `Solution` class to call the method, without modifying the internal state of your `Solution` object. It would be better to use `static` and call the method like this:

```
public class Solution {
    public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) { … your body method }
}

//in another class
int[] nums = {2, 7, 11, 15};
int target = 9;
int[] result = Solution.twoSum(nums, target);
```

In the Leetcode contest if I understand well it has been guaranteed there is always a solution to the problem, so you will always find a couple of indexes in the for loop meeting the conditions. In a more general situation where finding a solution cannot be guaranteed it could be better return a couple of indexes like `[-1, -1]`.
Then your method could be rewritten in the following way mantaining the same signature of the original method:

```
public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int index = 0; index < nums.length; index++) {
        final int key = target - nums[index];

        if (map.containsKey(key)) {
           return new int[] {map.get(key), index};
        }
        map.put(nums[index], index);
    }

    return new int[] {-1, -1};
}
```

Comment: @Emma You are welcome and I'm agree with you, Leetcode in this case could define the problem in a better way.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add on to the C++ answer.

- You're assuming that a solution exists, due to lack of break condition in the loop. That may work for Leetcode; however, that is not a reasonable assumption. If a solution doesn't exist, you're in Undefined Behavior Land by accessing the array out of bounds.
- You don't need `return vector<int>{index, iter-second};`. Just `return {index, iter->second};` works due to implicit construction of vector from an initializer list.
- Assuming it's possible that a solution doesn't exist, you might want to return an empty vector or a `std::optional`.

Answer (score 3):

## Methods vs. Functions

None of your three solutions are object-oriented. Note: there is nothing wrong with that, in fact, the problem domain is really anemic, so there is not much to model with objects anyway.

However, not being object-oriented, there is no need for objects here. In all three versions you use *instance methods* (or *member functions* as C++ calls them). The defining characteristics of instance methods are that they are dispatched ad-hoc (often dynamically) and thus allow for (runtime) ad-hoc polymorphism, and that they have privileged access to the internal representation of the object (via their *invisible zeroth `this` argument*, or in Python the very much visible first argument). But, you are not using either of those two features, so there is no need for those instance methods to be … well … instance methods. They should just be functions (or in the case of Java *static methods*), somewhat like this:

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int> &nums, int target) { /* … */ }
```

```java
class Solution {
    public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) { /* … */ }
}
```

```py
def twoSum(nums, target):
    // …
```

## Data types

There is no restriction in the problem description about the size of the numbers, nor the size of the array. In Java, `int` can only store numbers from -2147483648 to +2147483647. In C++, `int` is only guaranteed to be able to store numbers from -32767 to +32767, so if your array is longer than ~30000 items or any of the numbers in the array or the target number are outside of that range, it is not guaranteed to work!

Python `int` can be arbitrarily large, so there is no problem, but for Java, you should use [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html). C++ doesn't have a suitable type, unfortunately, but you can use third-party libraries such as [`Boost.Multiprecision`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: A bit of nitpicking: Member functions in C++ are statically dispatched unless declared `virtual`. I think your generalization over the three languages is a bit inaccurate there. The conclusion remains nonetheless the same.

Comment: @EmmaX: Thanks, clarified.

Answer (score 2):

I have one suggestion for the Java version.

### Instead of using `java.util.Map#containsKey`, you can use `java.util.Map#get`.

In your code, you can make it short and faster by fetching the value and checking the nullity.

**Before**

```java
if (map.containsKey(target - nums[index])) {
   //[...]
   indices[0] = map.get(target - nums[index]);
   //[...]
}
```

**After**

```java
Integer value = map.get(target - nums[index]);
if (value != null) {
   //[...]
   indices[0] = value;
   //[...]
}
```